# Trying to create a word counter but my statement gives a typeerror in python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, typeerror

new to python ad trying to understand how to troubleshoot this issue-

```
   import pandas as pd
    import pyodbc
    from collections import Counter, defaultdict
    import numpy as np
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                          'Server=10.50.3.110\ds;'
                          'Database=xx;'
                          'UID=xx;'
                          'PWD=xx@#Fxx*xx>m;'
                          )


transcripts = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM forward.claims", conn)

conn.close()


transcripts['Transcript'] = transcripts['Transcript'].str.lower()

Terms =  [ 
             ['deductible','deductible'], 
             ['deductible','deduct'], 
             ['deductible','deducted'], 
             ['pre-approved','pre approved'], 
             ['pre-approved','pre approve'], 
             ['medical records','medical records'], 
             ['medical records','medical record'],]
Terms = pd.DataFrame(Terms, columns = ['Terms', 'Keyword'])

list_of_results = []
count = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
for index, row in transcripts.iterrows():
    for string_to_search in Terms['Keyword'].to_list():
        if string_to_search in row['Transcript']:
            count[string_to_search] += row['Transcript'].count(string_to_search)
            list_of_results.append((row['InteractionId'],string_to_search))
            

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-88446cec2859>", line 5, in <module>
    if string_to_search in row['Transcript']:

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

transcripts
Out[22]: 
            InteractionId  ...                                         Transcript
0      200323337020200120  ...                                    donald disease 
1      200323337020200120  ...  does the same thing like the 250 well it's a 2...
2      200323337020200120  ...           do you guys have somebody speak spanish 
3      200323337020200129  ...                do you want me to get a translator 

[39024 rows x 5 columns]
```

Why does this error occur and how do I resolve this error? is there a universal solution to this particular typeerror? Please also find reprex of transcripts above

Comment: `row['Transcript']` is `None` at some point during your code execution. That returns the error because you can't check `if  <something>in None`

Comment: It's likely that one of your 39,024 rows has a None in that column.  Easy to check for.  `if row['Transcript'] and string_to_search in row['Transcript']:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got at least one row for which `row['Transcript']` is actually just a `None`.
You can avoid this error in one of many ways, but the simplest might be to first check for this case, in the same logical clause.
So instead of -

```
if string_to_search in row['Transcript']:
```

Try -

```
if row['Transcript'] is not None and string_to_search in row['Transcript']:
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have stated, `row['Transcript']` is `None` at some point. Checking if this expression is `not None` beforehand will help. I just wanted to give you a hint if you are looking for an elegant solution: [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)